# gtk: set active window

Tags: python, window, pygtk, gtk

I have a `gtk.Window`. How do I set it to be the active window? I can call `is_active()` to see whether it already is, but I don't see where to make it active.

Bonus points: given a `gtk.Widget`, how do I make the window it is a part of the active window?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ah thanks to [this thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/125408), the answer is to call `gtk.Window.present()`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me (thanks Dan D for pointing out wnck)

```
def activate(window):
    screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
    screen.force_update()
    wnckwin = [win for win in screen.get_windows() if win.get_xid() == window.window.xid][0]
    wnckwin.activate(gtk.gdk.x11_get_server_time(window.window))
```

Answer (score 1):

if `W` is a `gtk.Window`:

```
import wnck
wnck.window_get(W.window.xid).activate()
```

Comment: I get "xid attribute not supported"; i'm on Windows, btw, so if i can get the `hwnd` then i can figure it out.

Comment: oh, yes, libwnck doesn't exist for MS Windows as X11 WMs don't exist there either

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `gtk.Dialog.run` (if it's a Dialog) aditional to `gtk.Window.present`