# how to make gtk.Window() active?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have read [gtk: set active window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393185/gtk-set-active-window) but i want to do it without installation of wnck, also gtk.Windows.present() dont work for me:(

Comment: If `present()` is not working then it is because your window manager is doing something different with the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some big investigations I could say that there is no other way without `wnck` it yor window manager dont handle `present()` correct.